# php mysql populate several dynamic dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

i am creating 3 drop down list  that is based on the selection of each other so the first selection i normal but the second is dependent on the first selection and the third is dependent on the second selection  this is the table structure is like

category subcategory and subsubcategory

## this is the code

```
<?php

require "config.php"; //  Database details 
?>

<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 3.2//en">

<html>

<head>
<title>Demo of Three Multiple drop down list box from plus2net</title>
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Arachnophilia 4.0">
<meta name="FORMATTER" content="Arachnophilia 4.0">
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
function reload(form)
{
var val=form.cat.options[form.cat.options.selectedIndex].value; 
self.location='dd3.php?cat=' + val ;
}
function reload3(form)
{
var val=form.cat.options[form.cat.options.selectedIndex].value; 
var val2=form.subcat.options[form.subcat.options.selectedIndex].value; 

self.location='dd3.php?cat=' + val + '&cat3=' + val2 ;
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<?



$quer2=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT category,cat_id FROM category order by category"); 

$cat=$_GET['cat']; 
if(isset($cat) and strlen($cat) > 0){
$quer=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT subcategory,subcat_id FROM subcategory where cat_id=$cat order by subcategory"); 
}else{$quer=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT subcategory,subcat_id FROM subcategory order by subcategory"); } 




$cat3=$_GET['cat3'];
if(isset($cat3) and strlen($cat3) > 0){
$quer3=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT subcat2 FROM subcategory2 where subcat_id=$cat3 order by subcat2"); 
}else{$quer3=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT subcat2 FROM subcategory2 order by subcat2"); } 


echo "<form method=post name=f1 action='dd3ck.php'>";

echo "<select name='cat' onchange=\"reload(this.form)\"><option value=''>Select one</option>";
while($noticia2 = mysql_fetch_array($quer2)) { 
if($noticia2['cat_id']==@$cat){echo "<option selected value='$noticia2[cat_id]'>$noticia2[category]</option>"."<BR>";}
else{echo  "<option value='$noticia2[cat_id]'>$noticia2[category]</option>";}
}
echo "</select>";

echo "<select name='subcat' onchange=\"reload3(this.form)\"><option value=''>Select one</option>";
while($noticia = mysql_fetch_array($quer)) { 
if($noticia['subcat_id']==@$cat3){echo "<option selected value='$noticia[subcat_id]'>$noticia[subcategory]</option>"."<BR>";}
else{echo  "<option value='$noticia[subcat_id]'>$noticia[subcategory]</option>";}
}
echo "</select>";

echo "<select name='subcat3' ><option value=''>Select one</option>";
while($noticia = mysql_fetch_array($quer3)) { 
echo  "<option value='$noticia[subcat2]'>$noticia[subcat2]</option>";
}
echo "</select>";



echo "<input type=submit value='Submit the form data'></form>";
?>

</body>

</html>
```

can anyone help me ??

## and this is the output when i run this code

```
0){ $quer=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT subcategory,subcat_id FROM subcategory where cat_id=$cat order by subcategory"); }else{$quer=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT subcategory,subcat_id FROM subcategory order by subcategory"); } $cat3=$_GET['cat3']; if(isset($cat3) and strlen($cat3) > 0){ $quer3=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT subcat2 FROM subcategory2 where subcat_id=$cat3 order by subcat2"); }else{$quer3=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT subcat2 FROM subcategory2 order by subcat2"); } echo "
"; echo ""; echo ""; echo ""; echo "
"; ?>
```

Comment: There's something going wrong with your PHP-Code... display it properly.

Comment: the code above is as i wrote but the  second it is not a php code it is the output on the browser when i try to run the code

Comment: Are you sure to have the right `<?php`-Tags (e.g. no `<?`, only `<?php`?) and that your filename ends with `.php`?

Answer (score 0):

There is only a `<?` not a `<?php` at the start of the lower php code and the > from the if statement ends it I think. But that might not be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

May be PHP short tags have been disabled in your server. So if you are using short tags for PHP it won't work.

Check this link for how to enable short tags in PHP. http://www.tomjepson.co.uk/enabling-short-tags-in-php/

But if you can't enable short tags, then you need to correctly open the PHP tag

`<?` is wrong it should be `<?php`. Change that in your code. The complete code will be :

```
<?php

require "config.php"; //  Database details 
?>

<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 3.2//en">

<html>

<head>
<title>Demo of Three Multiple drop down list box from plus2net</title>
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Arachnophilia 4.0">
<meta name="FORMATTER" content="Arachnophilia 4.0">
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
function reload(form)
{
var val=form.cat.options[form.cat.options.selectedIndex].value; 
self.location='dd3.php?cat=' + val ;
}
function reload3(form)
{
var val=form.cat.options[form.cat.options.selectedIndex].value; 
var val2=form.subcat.options[form.subcat.options.selectedIndex].value; 

self.location='dd3.php?cat=' + val + '&cat3=' + val2 ;
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php



$quer2=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT category,cat_id FROM category order by category"); 

$cat=$_GET['cat']; 
if(isset($cat) and strlen($cat) > 0){
$quer=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT subcategory,subcat_id FROM subcategory where cat_id=$cat order by subcategory"); 
}else{$quer=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT subcategory,subcat_id FROM subcategory order by subcategory"); } 




$cat3=$_GET['cat3'];
if(isset($cat3) and strlen($cat3) > 0){
$quer3=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT subcat2 FROM subcategory2 where subcat_id=$cat3 order by subcat2"); 
}else{$quer3=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT subcat2 FROM subcategory2 order by subcat2"); } 


echo "<form method=post name=f1 action='dd3ck.php'>";

echo "<select name='cat' onchange=\"reload(this.form)\"><option value=''>Select one</option>";
while($noticia2 = mysql_fetch_array($quer2)) { 
if($noticia2['cat_id']==@$cat){echo "<option selected value='$noticia2[cat_id]'>$noticia2[category]</option>"."<BR>";}
else{echo  "<option value='$noticia2[cat_id]'>$noticia2[category]</option>";}
}
echo "</select>";

echo "<select name='subcat' onchange=\"reload3(this.form)\"><option value=''>Select one</option>";
while($noticia = mysql_fetch_array($quer)) { 
if($noticia['subcat_id']==@$cat3){echo "<option selected value='$noticia[subcat_id]'>$noticia[subcategory]</option>"."<BR>";}
else{echo  "<option value='$noticia[subcat_id]'>$noticia[subcategory]</option>";}
}
echo "</select>";

echo "<select name='subcat3' ><option value=''>Select one</option>";
while($noticia = mysql_fetch_array($quer3)) { 
echo  "<option value='$noticia[subcat2]'>$noticia[subcat2]</option>";
}
echo "</select>";



echo "<input type=submit value='Submit the form data'></form>";
?>

</body>

</html>
```